# find all points in t2 within 1000m of all points in t1

Tags: postgresql, distance, postgis

I have 2 tables, `t1` and `t2`, each with a `geography` type column called `pts_geog`, and each with a column `id` which is a unit identifier.  I want to add a column to `t1` which counts *how many* units from `t2` are within a distance of 1000m to the any given point in t1. Both tables reasonably large, with each about 150000 rows. To compute the distance of each point in `t1` to each point in `t2` however results in a very expensive operation, so I am looking for some guidance as to what I'm doing has any hope. I have never been able to complete this operation because out of memory. I could split the operation somehow (with a `where` along another dimension of `t1`), but I need more help. Here is the `select` that I would like to use:

```
select
    count(nullif(
        ST_DWithin(
        g1.pts_geog,
        g2.gts_geog,
        1000,
        false),
        false)) as close_1000
from
    t1 as g1,
    t2 as g2
where
    g1.pts_geog IS NOT NULL
    and
    g2.pts_geog IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY g1.id
```

suggested answer and EXPLAIN:

```
airbnb=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE
airbnb-> SELECT t1.listing_id, count(*)
airbnb-> FROM paris as t1
airbnb-> JOIN airdna_property as t2
airbnb-> ON ST_DWithin( t1.pts_geog, t2.pts_geog,1000 )
airbnb-> WHERE t2.city='Paris'
airbnb-> group by t1.listing_id;
                                                                           QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=1030317.33..1030386.39 rows=6906 width=8) (actual time=2802071.616..2802084.109 rows=54400 loops=1)
   Group Key: t1.listing_id
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..1030282.80 rows=6906 width=8) (actual time=0.827..2604319.421 rows=785571807 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on airdna_property t2  (cost=0.00..74893.44 rows=141004 width=56) (actual time=0.131..738.133 rows=141506 loops=1)
               Filter: (city = 'Paris'::text)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 400052
         ->  Index Scan using paris_pts_geog_idx on paris t1  (cost=0.41..6.77 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.133..17.865 rows=5552 loops=141506)
               Index Cond: (pts_geog && _st_expand(t2.pts_geog, '1000'::double precision))
               Filter: ((t2.pts_geog && _st_expand(pts_geog, '1000'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(pts_geog, t2.pts_geog, '1000'::double precision, true))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 3260
 Planning time: 0.197 ms
 Execution time: 2802086.005 ms
```

output of version:

```
                                                 version                                                  |            postgis_version            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.5.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005, 64-bit | 2.2 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
```

**Update 2**

This is after creating the indices as suggested. notice that the number of rows slightly increased because I added new data, but this is still the same size of problem. it takes 52 minutes. It still says `Seq Scan` on `city`, and I don't understand: why doesn't it do an index scan there, given I created one?

```
                                                                           QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=904989.83..905049.21 rows=5938 width=8) (actual time=3118569.759..3118581.444 rows=54400 loops=1)
   Group Key: t1.listing_id
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..904960.14 rows=5938 width=8) (actual time=2.624..2881694.755 rows=837837851 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on airdna_property t2  (cost=0.00..74842.84 rows=121245 width=56) (actual time=2.263..949.073 rows=151018 loops=1)
               Filter: (city = 'Paris'::text)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 435564
         ->  Index Scan using paris_pts_geog_idx on paris t1  (cost=0.41..6.84 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.139..18.555 rows=5548 loops=151018)
               Index Cond: (pts_geog && _st_expand(t2.pts_geog, '1000'::double precision))
               Filter: ((t2.pts_geog && _st_expand(pts_geog, '1000'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(pts_geog, t2.pts_geog, '1000'::double precision, true))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 3257
 Planning time: 0.377 ms
 Execution time: 3118583.203 ms
(12 rows)
```

Comment: The count is weird.  Why not use the distance calc in the where clause, then count all rows?

Comment: paste the result of `SELECT * FROM version(), postgis_version();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you're doing is selecting the count just move the clause out of the select list to trim up the join.

```
SELECT t1.id, count(*)
FROM t1
JOIN t2
  ON ST_DWithin( t1.pts_geog, t2.pts_geog, 1000 )
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

If you need an index, which `ST_DWithin` can use run this..

```
CREATE INDEX ON t1 USING gist (pts_geog);
CREATE INDEX ON t2 USING gist (pts_geog);
VACUUM ANALYZE t1;
VACUUM ANALYZE t2;
```

Now run the `SELECT` query above.

### Update 2

Your plan shows that you have seq scan on city, so create an index on city and then we'll see what more we can do

```
CREATE INDEX ON airdna_property (city);
ANALYZE airdna_property;
```

Comment: thanks, looks much nicer. it's been running for 40 minutes now. i'll let it run overnight.

Comment: @FlorianOswald do you have a gist index on t1.pts_geog and t2.pts_geog, and what version of postgis/postgresql are you using? It should be pretty fast.

Comment: i'm afraid i don't understand (close to beginner with this). im sure you don't want my data copied onto a gist, so you'll have to explain how to do this. i get a sense that this should be much faster and I'm doing something stupid, so thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: @FlorianOswald what is your SRID? the distance param is based on that I think. This might be why it's going so slow, you might be doing N^2 because 1000 units might be huge.

Comment: @FlorianOswald btw, worth mentioning too if you do not have a GIST index on on the pts_geog as mentioned above (which you can see with `\d t1`), then it'll be in your best interest to cancel the query add the index and rerun it. The 40 minutes is nothing.

Comment: @markg Since the columns are of type `geography`, the unit in `st_dwithin` is meters

Comment: The op already said and has always said these were already typed geography. He likely doesn't have an index. He didn't know what GIST was.

Comment: ok guys, so this query completed successfully, but again after a very long time. I did create the GIST index as suggested. i updated my question with a precise statement of my code and EXPLAIN, in case this is helpful.

Comment: would it make sense to upgrade to postgresql 9.6 and use the parallel query functionality? i can see that my query uses 100% of a single CPU, with very low memory requirements. so if that could be distributed over 8 available cores, that would probably help.

Comment: ok @EvanCarroll so this now completes in 46 minutes. i updated my question with more details for you. do you think that is what I have to deal with or do you still think that this should really be faster? thanks again.

Comment: @FlorianOswald type this, `CREATE INDEX ON airdna_property (city); ANALYZE airdna_property;` and try again (paste the updated plan)

Comment: hi @EvanCarroll, i updated this again. thanks for your help.

Comment: @FlorianOswald did you run the ANALYZE part, paste the results of `\d airdna_property` and `\d paris`. Try to run `set enable_seqscan=0;` and rerun the query and paste the result.